# Exibir cor hexadecimal com php vindo MySQL

Tags: php

Gostaria de exibir em uma página que estou desenvolvendo um valor hexadecimal que está armazenado em meu banco de dados. Fiz alguns testes, mas sem sucesso.

Tentei fazer algo assim:

```
<?php echo "background-color:".$ProdCor->Cor;.""; ?>
```

O valor no campo do banco está assim:

```
#ffff00
```

Estou tentado mostrar a cor em um campo da página.

O CSS que está relacionado ao campo é esse:

```
.tovar_color_select {padding-bottom:19px;}
.tovar_color_select p {
    margin-bottom:13px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333;
}
.tovar_color_select a {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:32px;
    height:22px;
}
```

.tovar_color_select a:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:-4px;
    top:-4px;
    right:-4px;
    bottom:-4px;
    border:1px solid #e9e9e9;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.tovar_color_select a:hover:before,
.tovar_color_select a.active:before {
    border:2px solid #333;
}

A tag completa é essa:

`<div class="tovar_color_select">
<p>SELECIONE A COR</p>
<?php foreach($ResCor as $ProdCor ) { ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" ><?php echo "background-color:".$ProdCor->Cor; ?></a>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: E o resto do código do campo? Você está utilizando CSS inline ou inseriu isso dentro do arquivo CSS?

Comment: Tem um erro de sintaxe, um `;` no meio da concatenação. Além disso, apesar de não causar um erro na saída, concatenar uma string com `""` no final é sem sentido nesse contexto. Bastaria `<?php echo "background-color:".$ProdCor->Cor; ?>` que pode ser abreviado para `<?='background-color:'.$ProdCor->Cor?>` em versões mais novas do PHP (em mais velhas, depende de configuração)

Comment: Olá @Bacco, valeu pela dica, mas não deu certo, editei a pergunta para tentar mostrar o que preciso.

Comment: @adventistapr testou minha resposta?

Comment: Olá @Thiago Magalhães, também não deu certo.

Comment: Seguindo código da minha resposta, altere o `background-color: <?= $ProdCor->Cor ?>` por `background-color: #333`. Ele deve imprimir um quadrado com a cor especificada. Verificou se a cor está sendo retornada corretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
<?php foreach($ResCor as $ProdCor ) { ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
      <div style="background-color: <?= $ProdCor->Cor ?>; width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Criei uma `div` adicionando o `css inline`, onde defino a cor do `background` que vem por meio do `PHP` e fixo suas dimensões. É importante lembrar de definir as dimensões pois caso não coloque nenhum caractere dentro, a `div` não terá uma `width` e nem uma `height`, logo não existira espaço para que o `background` possa preencher com a cor desejada.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela grande ajuda.